# Least Square with quadratic constraint

Tags: mathematical-optimization, probability-or-statistics, linear-algebra

I have the following problem:For $\theta \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times1}$,
$\quad$  $Y=X\theta+W$

where $W \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times1}$ is the complex additive white Gaussian noise.    $X \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n},Y \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times 1}$ are known. I'd like to solve the following problem:

$\qquad$  $\mathop{\arg\min}_{\theta} \ \ \mathrm{J} (\theta) = \|Y-X\theta\|^2$

$\qquad$  subject to: $\ \ \theta^TA\theta = 0$

where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is known, $T$ denote the transpose. Can I solve this problem by Lagrange multipliers and how to do this? And how to get a close-form solution  like Least Square with linear equality constraints?

Thanks